# Merge two groups of Core Data objects into one datastore

Tags: core-data

My app data model is built to take in a large amount of entities within entities within entities as pictured below. I did approximately two hours of research before I caved and asked on this forum, so I made the effort to find out for myself and I'm not just wasting time.

Anyway, what I plan to do is have one local Recorder object that gets filled by the user, but then my app also needs to have the ability to take in another Recorder object from a bluetooth transfer and merge all of the incoming Recorder's entities and entities related to those entities and so on.

How can I go about moving the incoming Recorder's contents into the local copy and also find duplicate Match objects as they appear?

Is there an easier way besides using for loops to iterate through everything?

[image: Recorder has several Regionals, which has several Teams, which has several Matches]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear what you're asking, but I'll take a stab.

Your diagram shows no subentities. It does show different entities that are connected by relationships. From my reading of what you asked, you aren't merging subentities. You are simply combining `NSManagedObject` instances from two different sources.

It's a straightforward job, once you tighten up your terminology. Implement a find-or-create class method for each of your entities. That means you'll have to decide what makes a Regional, or Team, or Match, unique. Each of the find-or-create methods will always return an instance of its entity, either by retrieving an existing one, or by inserting, populating, and returning a new one. Defining fetch requests will make this task less tedious.

When you receive a new batch of results to merge, start at the top object, walk the relationships, and find-or-create for each object in the incoming set.

It looks to me like your Recorder entity doesn't do much, and is complicating things. You probably do want that class defined, but not stored within the Core Data model. A model of Regions, Teams, and Matches matches real world nicely, and makes the fetching/merging more obvious.

Comment: My apologies on misusing the word "subentities", I am new to Core Data, this is only like my fourth day with it. What might the find-or-create class method look like?(provide a pseudocode solution, if possible please) And should I add it in within a Category? I saw that a Category can be used to implement methods needed for entities, but I'm not sure about what cases would be best for the use of Categories.

Comment: Ok, I got it all fixed now exactly how you said. Thank you for helping me out. I appreciate being able to learn something new